# Find object by attribute

Tags: ruby, class, instance

I have a ruby class like this:

```
class Table
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @columns = {}
  end
end
```

I'm creating different objects:

```
table_1 = Table.new("First")
table_2 = Table.new("Second")
table_3 = Table.new("Third")
```

How can I find among the objects of the `Table` class the object having "Second" as `name` attribute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a reference to an array of instances in the class.

```
class Table
  @instances = []
  class << self
    attr_accessor :instances
  end

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @columns = {}
    self.class.instances << self
  end
end
```

Then you can get all the instances by

```
Table.instances
```

This, however, will prevent all the `Table` objects being garbage collected, so it is only feasible if you have only a small amount of `Table`s and that amount never grows, otherwise you'll have a memory leak.

Comment: @Andrey's solution is the shortest but this one allowed me to keep objects

Comment: Nice solution! @GrahamSlick just a short note: you never said in your question that you wanted to keep objects ;) But good you've found a suitable solution!

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I know bc I only realized it was removing objects once I implemented yours :D Sorry about that, but thanks a lot for your help too

Comment: @GrahamSlick :D as I say, no probs, glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Without creating any additional structures of data:

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(Table).find { |object| object.instance_variable_get(:@name) == "Second" }
=> #<Table:0x007f9f912b0ce0 @columns={}, @name="Second">
```

Comment: Further question, how can I distinguish garbage from non-garbage objects?

Comment: And how can I select only non-garbage objects without forcing a gc?

Comment: @Aetherus, I do not yet have discovered the full power of `ObjectSpace` and GC, so can't answer the question about distinquishing between garbage and non-garbage objects.

Comment: But,  `.instance_variable_get(:@name)` - for  what here? I think, `ObjectSpace.each_object(Table).find { |object| object.name == "Second" }` will work the same in this example, no?

Comment: @AlexGolubenko no, there is no `attr_reader` for `@name` instance variable :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko oh, sure, sorry for this, I just a little not quite awake :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's add a getter method for the name attribute

```
class Table
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @columns = {}
  end
end
```

Now, if you have an array of Table objects

```
arr = [Table.new("First"), Table.new("Second"), Table.new("Third")]
```

You can find by name

```
arr.find { |table| table.name == "Second" }
 => #<Table:0x007f862107eb18 @name="Second", @columns={}>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use enumerable [`find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) or any similar method from the enumerable module:

```
class Table
  attr_reader :name
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @columns = {}
  end
end

table_1 = Table.new("First")
table_2 = Table.new("Second")
table_3 = Table.new("Third")

x = [table_1, table_2, table_3].find { |t| t.name == "Second" }

puts x.name => "Second"
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have reader on `name` in `Table`:

```
class Table
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @columns = {}
  end
end
```

I'd encourage you to store these `Table` classes' objects in a list/array:

```
table_1 = Table.new("First")
table_2 = Table.new("Second")
table_3 = Table.new("Third")

tables = [table_1, table_2, table_3]
```

Which can then be used for finding it using `find`(as mentioned in one of the answers) or [`detect`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect):

```
tables.detect { |t| t.name == "Second" } #=> table_2 object
```

If you'd like to go one more step ahead then we can have another class maintaining this array:

```
class TableList
  attr_reader :tables
  def initialize
    @tables = tables
  end

  def add(table)
    @tables << table
  end

  def find_by_name(name)
    tables.detect{ |table| table.name == name }
  end
end
```

Which can then be used as:

```
table_1 = Table.new("First")
table_2 = Table.new("Second")
table_3 = Table.new("Third")
table_list = TableList.new
table_list.add(table_1)
table_list.add(table_2)
table_list.add(table_3)

table_list.find_by_name('Second') #=> table_2 object
```